# Есть матрица. Надо создать код, который определяет минимальный элемент в столбце и его положение

Tags: c

```
const int m = 4, n = 4;
int i, j;
int arr[m][n];
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        printf("arr[%d][%d]=", i, j);
        scanf_s("%d", &arr[i][j]);
    }
puts("Матрицы имеет вид:");
for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
        printf("%4d", arr[i][j]);
    putchar('\n');
}

int arrMin[n][m];
int min;
for (j = 0; j < n; j++)
{
    min = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++)
    {
        if (arr[min][j] > arr[i][j])
        {
            min = i;
        }
    }
    arrMin[i][j] = arr[min][j];
}
printf("Минимальные элементы столбцов:\n");
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    //for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
    printf("%4d(%d,%d)",arrMin[i][j],i,j);;
}
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Что тут не так?

Comment: в си нету матриц! никаких! а вот массив указателей на массив есть

Answer (score 0):

`arrmin` может быть быть одномерным массивом, хранящим номер строки минимума в столбце (а в настоящий момент выводится что попало)
[(ideone)](https://ideone.com/Uuc3G6)

```
int arrMin[n];
...
arrMin[j] = min;
...
printf("%4d(%d,%d)",arr[arrMin[i]][i],arrMin[i], i);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
...
int arrMin[m];
int min;

for(j = 0; j < m; ++j)
{
    int min = 0;
    for(i = 1; i < n; ++i)
    {
        if (arr[i][j] < arr[min][j]);
    }
    arrMin[j] = min;
}
for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
{
    printf("В %d столбце в %d  строке хранится минимальный элемент равный %d", j, arrMin[j], arr[arrMin[j]][j]);
    putchar('\n');
}
...
```